# Filter a list from another list

Tags: python, list

I have two list (i.e., queryset and list) :

`filter_perceptions` :

```
<QuerySet [<Perception: Perception #0000001>, <Perception: Perception #0000009>, <Perception: Perception #0000017>, <Perception: Perception #0000018>]>
```

and another list

`results` :

```
[{u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000018>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f9264c56780>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000017>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f9264c562d0>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000016>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f926532bc30>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000015>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f9264c178c0>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000014>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f9264c17f50>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000013>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f9264c17fa0>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000012>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f9264c17960>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000011>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a3050>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000010>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a30a0>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000009>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a30f0>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000008>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a3140>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000007>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a3190>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000006>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a31e0>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000005>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a3230>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000004>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a3280>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000003>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a32d0>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000002>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a3320>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000001>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a3370>}]
```

I'd like to create a new list with the last two lists. In fact, I want to filter `results` so that it remains the lists which agree with the perceptions of `filter_perceptions`. Could anyone have an idea how we could cleverly do such thing?

Here is an example of the remaining list should be

```
[{u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000018>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f9264c56780>}, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000017>, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000009>, {u'object': <Perception: Perception #0000001>, u'cols': <generator object items_for_result at 0x7f92643a3370>}]
```

Thanks!

**P.S.** Please let me know if the question is unclear.

Comment: The question is unclear. Show a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[r for r in results if r['object'] in filter_perceptions]
```